# how to store pending notifications in an array in swift

Tags: swift, push-notification

I am trying to program a function which returns all the identifiers of pending notifications, which are repeating.

```
func getRepeatingNotificationsIds () -> [String] {
    
    var repatingNotification:[String] = []
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getPendingNotificationRequests {
        (requests)  in
        for request in requests{
            if (request.trigger?.repeats == true)
            {
                repatingNotification.append(request.identifier)
            }
            
         }
    }
    
    return repatingNotification
    
}
```

However the repatingNotification array remains empty when returned. Is it possible to maybe call repatingNotification by reference or something?

Comment: You can't do it that way, because the call is asynchrone. `return repatingNotification` will be called BEFORE the closure and `repatingNotification.append(request.identifier)` is called. So use a closure too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than trying to return a value, tell your function what you want it to do after collecting the requests by sending it a completion block.  As mentioned in a comment, what you have won't work because of timing.

Here's a trivial playground example that should give you the idea.

```
import UIKit

func getRepeatingNotificationsIds (completion: @escaping ([String])->()) {
    
    var repatingNotification:[String] = []
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getPendingNotificationRequests {
        (requests)  in
        for request in requests {
            if (request.trigger?.repeats == true) {
                repatingNotification.append(request.identifier)
            }
         }
        completion(repatingNotification)
    }
}

getRepeatingNotificationsIds { notifications in
    print(notifications)
}
```